# Why does using NSubstitue.Arg.Any<string> in one group of unit tests cause the last test in another set to fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper, nsubstitute

We had a very weird bug where running our full unit test suite with a set of new UnitTests would always fail the last test run in the new section (using ReSharper and NUnit for a Unity3D project).  However running the new set by itself all the tests would pass.

What made it weird was that changing the naming of the failing unit tests would cause the whole suite to pass in a seemingly random fashion.  We removed the world "_Multiple" and it seemed to work until we added a new test and that one failed but didn't have the word "_Multiple" in it at all.  At this point I knew the naming issued was a red herring and not actually the cause of the issue. It also was tested on multiple machines and always experienced the same behaviour.

We ended up narrowing the failure down when it was run with a suite of unit tests that was using Arg.Any on a non-NSubstitute object which basically ran

```
Assert.That(!string.Equals("Desired Value", Arg.Any<string>()));
```

Once we found that it was clear that I was misusing the Arg.Any() function.

My question is, why would changing the names of the functions affect the tests at all? And why would renaming all the tests to just be test1(), test2(), test3() etc allow all the tests to pass everytime when a more descriptive name wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSubstitute does hideous things with static state to get its particular syntax. `Arg.xyz` calls add argument specifications to a global queue, and these are cleared once a call to a substitute is made.

I'm guessing that changing the names of the tests causes a change in the order they are run, which in turn results in the problem being exposed or hidden. In one particular ordering, a call is made to a substitute which clears the errant `Arg.Any<string>()` specification, whereas with another ordering the specification causes a real call to be treated as configuring a stub value, or throws due to a mismatched argument.

Comment: Glad to know there is at least some basis in reality for what we were seeing! Thanks for the information!